# how to work on UISplitviewController in ipad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller

i am using iphone xcode 3.2.5  when i am run my app it show me this
error but it show only first time if i run second time it run proper
why this happen and what to do to solve this

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>       'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'UISplitViewController is only
>       supported when running under UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad'
>       *** Call stack at first throw: (  0   CoreFoundation                      0x00e57be9 **exceptionPreprocess + 185  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>       0x00fac5c2 objc_exception_throw + 47  2   CoreFoundation
>
>       0x00e10628 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136   3
>
>       CoreFoundation                      0x00e1059a +[NSException
>       raise:format:] + 58   4   UIKit
>
>       0x005cc37a -[UISplitViewController _commonInit] + 165     5   UIKit
>
>       0x005cc7d9 -[UISplitViewController initWithCoder:] + 92   6   UIKit
>
>       0x005aa9e4 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 2592    7   UIKit
>
>       0x005ab693 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 398  8   UIKit
>
>       0x0037c114 -[UIViewController initWithCoder:] + 513   9   UIKit
>
>       0x00386abe -[UINavigationController initWithCoder:] + 58  10  UIKit 
>       0x005aa9e4 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 2592    11  UIKit
>
>       0x005ab693 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 398  12  UIKit
>
>       0x0032a0d1 -[UINavigationBar initWithCoder:] + 445    13  UIKit
>
>       0x005aa9e4 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 2592    14  UIKit
>
>       0x005ab693 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 398  15  UIKit
>
>       0x0032957b -[UINavigationItem initWithCoder:] + 520   16  UIKit
>
>       0x005aa9e4 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 2592    17  UIKit
>
>       0x005ab693 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 398  18  UIKit
>
>       0x0037c0d5 -[UIViewController initWithCoder:] + 450   19  UIKit
>
>       0x004d1f38 -[UITableViewController initWithCoder:] + 64   20  UIKit
>
>       0x004c4265 -[UIClassSwapper initWithCoder:] + 237     21  UIKit
>
>       0x005aa9e4 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 2592    22  UIKit
>
>       0x005ab693 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 398  23  UIKit
>
>       0x004c3f08 -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 153    24  UIKit
>
>       0x005aa9e4 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 2592    25  UIKit
>
>       0x005aa2dc UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 792     26  UIKit
>
>       0x005ab693 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 398  27  UIKit
>
>       0x004c3200 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 804   28  UIKit
>
>       0x004c5081 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions)
>       loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 168    29  UIKit
>
>       0x002cf943 -[UIApplication _loadMainNibFile] + 172    30  UIKit
>
>       0x002d04ca -[UIApplication
>       _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:]
>       + 291     31  UIKit                               0x002dadb2 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1533    32  UIKit                               0x002d3202 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 71     33  UIKit
>
>       0x002d8732 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576   34  GraphicsServices
>
>       0x016faa36 PurpleEventCallback + 1550     35  CoreFoundation
>
>       0x00e39064
>       __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 52   36  CoreFoundation                      0x00d996f7
>   __CFRunLoopDoSource1
>       + 215     37  CoreFoundation                      0x00d96983 __CFRunLoopRun + 979     38  CoreFoundation                      0x00d96240 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208   39  CoreFoundation
>       0x00d96161 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97    40  UIKit
>       0x002cffa8 -[UIApplication _run] + 636    41  UIKit
>       0x002dc42e UIApplicationMain + 1160   42  People
>       0x00002328 main + 102     43  People
>       0x000022b9 start + 53 ) terminate called after throwing an instance
>       of 'NSException' Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `UISplitViewController` on iPhone, it's iPad-only feature.

> The UISplitViewController class is a container view controller that
>   manages the presentation of two side-by-side view controllers. You use
>   this class to implement a master-detail interface, in which the
>   left-side view controller presents a list of items and the right-side
>   presents details of the selected item. Split view controllers are for
>   use exclusively on iPad devices. Attempting to create one on other
>   devices results in an exception.

-
[UISplitViewController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISplitViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html).